# Teamcity 8- treat a build parameter as long or integer

Tags: teamcity

Using teamCity 8.0.5.
As part of my builds cleanup I would like to automatically remove any build older than the current 5 builds. For eg if my build.number = 12 , try and remove build 6. 
Unfortunately it seems that you can't cast %build.number%-6.

Using Teamcity how can you perform math on a build parameter?

I have tried 
%build.number% -1 along with wrapping it in ()

```
%system.PreviousBuild% =  \\server\path\Build%build.number%-6
```

my actual usage of this a command line post build event:

```
echo trying to remove directory %system.PreviousBuild%
IF EXIST %system.PreviousBuild% RD %system.PreviousBuild% /Q /S
```

result:

[09:19:09][Step 6/6] trying to remove director  \server\path\Build11-6

-------------------------UPDATE---------------------------

the answer below led me to the following solution:

NOTE: The important part here is to cast the build.number as an integer.
using powershell source code build step

Using powershell for the entire command worked for me:

```
Set-Variable -Name previousBuild -Value  (([int]%build.number%)-6).ToString()
Write-Output $previousBuild
Write-Output $env:PreviousBuildPath
Set-Variable -Name path -Value $env:PreviousBuildPath$previousBuild
Write-Output $path
if((Test-Path -path $path))
{
Remove-Item -Recurse -Force $path
}
```

Comment: just use powershell instead of command line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
set /a newBuildNumber=%build.number%-6
```

Then use %%newBuildNumber%% in your TC build script after the path.

```
\\server\path\Build%%newBuildNumber%%
```

Comment: Hi. I ended up going with the following. The suggestion you posted above didn't work at all in teamcity for me. I am not sure if your newBuildNumber was already defined somewhere in the build parameters but I couldn't get it to work. It wouldn't even work in just a powershell window.

However I am marking it as the answer because it did lead me to the correct answer.

Comment: newBuildNumber is not a TeamCity parameter, but a standard batch param. It is assigned a value equal to the TeamCity variable %build.number%-6. To use the value you have to use double %% instead of single % to identify it isn't a TeamCity param. Thanks for marking as answer.

Comment: If you try that in teamcity you would have just ended up with 40-6 as the result. I believe this is due to the build.number being cast as string. Its all good though. Have a happy Wednesday.